# Highcharts -- how to change line width programmatically and prevent resetting line width?

Tags: highcharts, hover, width, line

I created a line chart, and added a button whose click method make the line thicker (lineWidth 7pt). However, each time I mouse over the line or the legend, the line restore to its original width (which I believe is 2 pt). So I added the following plot options to disable the "hover" function:

```
    line: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false,
            }
        }
    },
```

But it only resolves the issue partially -- after I set lineWidth to 7 pt using the button, the line width will still be reset to its original 2 pt after I mouse over the legend or move mouse across the plotting area.

I have shared my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QNPYP/1/). Can anyone help me figure out how to prevent resetting the line width after changing its width to 7 pt?

Thanks in advance!

Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
 series.update({
            lineWidth:10
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNPYP/2/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()